# Recycle view not showing items when I start the app but after going to another fragment and back it works

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have to set up a recycle view inside a fragment. The problem is that when I start the app it shows nothing but if i switch to another fragment and go back all items are there. If i start the app and try to scroll through a the recycle view the first item and the last one will load. I tried searching for an answer but there is nothing useful. I mention i just started working in Android Studio.

That's the fragment code

```
public class Main_fragment extends Fragment {

    TextView titleText;

    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
    // Access it from anywhere
    static String FoodChoiceVar = "All food"; // Value set for test only. Maybe make an ENUM instead?

    public  Main_fragment() {
        // Needed empty constructor.
    }

    // Don't edit this method as you won't be able tu use "R".
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        titles.add("Breakfast");titles.add("Morning Snack");titles.add("Lunch");titles.add("AfterNoon Snack");titles.add("Dinner"); titles.add("Night Snack");
    }

    //Use this instead.
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);


        final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();

        titleText = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewFoodType);
        titleText.setText(FoodChoiceVar + "| MENU");


        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentRecycleView);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(c);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ViewAdapter adapter = new ViewAdapter(c,titles);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
```

The ViewAdapter

```
public class ViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodMenuViewHolder> {


    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<String> titleData;

    public ViewAdapter (Context context,List<String> titleData){
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.titleData = titleData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FoodMenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_menu_item,viewGroup,false);

        FoodMenuViewHolder holder = new FoodMenuViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodMenuViewHolder foodMenuViewHolder, int i) {

        String title = titleData.get(i);
        foodMenuViewHolder.titleText.setText(title);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titleData.size();
    }
}
```

The view holder

```
public class FoodMenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    public TextView titleText;

    public FoodMenuViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        titleText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ItemText);
    }
}
```

I have captured 2 short videos to show what is happening
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17wvlhPUT5R0SN38C2TbgBv_AP8awQUI3/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LJ0Xg4p8Q4a4nyGPSHdVQhBlYOYYi1Pv/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your adapter it's losing itself, so try to get the context for layout inflater from viewgroup in onCreateViewHolder.

this:

```js
    public FoodMenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new FoodMenuViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_menu_item, viewGroup, false);
    }
```

And to avoid anoying error, put a execption in getItemCount().

This:

```js
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(titleData != null) {
           return titleData.size();
        } else {
           return 0;
        }
    }
```

And try to use context instead of Fragment Activity

```js
        final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();
```

to

```js
        final Context c = getContext();
```

Comment: I have managed to fix it by setting a fixed dp to the elements in the layout used for the recycle view. But I tried with  Context c = getContext();  and that seems to be working now. I retry testing it with a card view again to see if it's working.

Comment: In android we usually use context for everything, only in a very specific case you'll use Activity, fragment or something like that. So try to avoid it, if you can use context.